# Register callback function to go from android(JNI or JNA)

Tags: android, go, java-native-interface, cgo

Dears,
I'm trying to running go-library (build to aarch64) on android. And want to register callback function to go.
My idea is passing "Callback" via unsafe pointer, and unmarshall and use on go.

```java
public class MainActivity {
    public interface lib extends Library {

        //register callback on go side. passing Callback function.
        void onReceive(Callback cb);
    }

    // this is callback which is want to register to go.
    private static Callback cb = new Callback() {
        public void receive(String message) {
            //do something
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        final lib myLib = Native.loadLibrary("myLib", lib.class);
        myLib.onReceive(cb); // I'm not sure. Is it possible?
    }
}
```

And now, on Go.

```golang
package main

import (
    "C"
    "unsafe"
)

var callback func

//export
func onReceive(fn unsafe.Pointer) {
    // I think, can use if convert unsafe pointer to func.
    // But, I can't find way.
    // callback = (*func)(unsafe.Pointer(fn)) ?
}

func doSomething() {
    // do something.
    // and callback.
    // callback(C.CString("this is from go!")
}
```

How to convert Pointer to func?

Comment: Hmm, you simply cannot cast pointer to function, even then they uses different ABI. And I don't think that java side is aware of C strings. You have to use jni/jna interface (on C side with callback to go side) to interact with.

Comment: But I'm not really sure of, you can try to wrap the pointer with this: https://github.com/LaevusDexter/asmcgocall the one thing is that asmcgocall assumes that pointer is a C callback with the only one pointer-size argument, so that's what cgo does behind the scene.